# Designated Initializer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, init, designated-initializer

what is this saying as stated in apples doc:

> Sometimes the designated initializer of a superclass may be sufficient for the subclass, and so there is no need for the subclass to implement its own designated initializer. Other times, a class’s designated initializer may be an overridden version of its superclass's designated initializer. This is frequently the case when the subclass needs to supplement the work performed by the superclass’s designated initializer, even though the subclass does not add any instance variables of its own (or the instance variables it does add don’t require explicit initialization).
>
> [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3)

Is it saying that i don't have to create a designated initializer for the subclass and the superclass designated initializer will suffice and if so how will the subclasses properties be initialized? and in what scenario if this allowed? How would that work?

Also if your overriding the DI how can you call that method from the subclass as the parent class has the same DI as you do? What does it mean that it needs to supplement the work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

There is a superclass `A` with an `initWithName:` DI.

Now you create subclass `B`. If you want the same DI and you don't need any additional initialization, then there is nothing to do with the `init` method. You simply call:

```
B *someBObject = [[B alloc] initWithName:@"A Name"];
```

This creates the `B` object and calls the `initWithName:` method from `A`.

Now if your `B` class needs to do supplemental work in the `initWithName:` method, then you add this to `B.m`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
    self = [super initWithName:name];
    if (self) {
        // do some additional stuff to initialize this "B" instance
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: For the first part what your saying is in the case where i dont have any init methods in my subclass but i do have other methods and properties but yet if invoke the DI init method will the properties and methods in the subclass be initialized as well? or will it just be the parent class and up classes that are initialized?

Comment: If you have anything in the subclass that must be initialized, then your subclass must override any needed initializers so it can properly initialize those values.